# recursion method inside ruby minesweeper game stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, recursion, minesweeper

I am triggering endless recursion when trying to make a method that pulls up tiles when they are a zero. I have been testing by entering the following in irb:

```
class Board
  attr_accessor :size, :board

  def initialize(size = gets.chomp.to_i)
    @size = size
    @board = (1..@size).map { |x| ["L"] * @size }
  end

  def print_board
    @board.map { |row| puts row.join }
  end
end

class Mine
  attr_accessor :proxi, :row, :col

  def initialize(proxi)
    @proxi = proxi
    @row = 0
    @col = 0
    @random = Random.new
    check_position
  end

  def check_position
    if @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] != "L"
      @row = @random.rand(1..@proxi.board.length)
      @col = @random.rand(1..@proxi.board[0].length)
      check_position
    else
      map_position
    end
  end

  def map_position
    @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] = "*"
  end
end

b = Board.new(20)
m = (1..b.size * 2).map { |i| i = Mine.new(b) }

class Detector
  attr_accessor :board, :proxi, :row, :col, :value

  def initialize(board, proxi)
    @board = board
    @proxi = proxi
    @row = 0
    @col = 0
    @value = 0
  end

  def mine?
    if @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] == "*"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def detect
    (@row - 1..@row + 1).each do |r|
      (@col - 1..@col + 1).each do |c|
        unless (r - 1 < 0 || r - 1 > @proxi.size - 1) || (c - 1 < 0 || c - 1 > @proxi.size - 1)
          @value += 1 if @proxi.board[r - 1][c - 1] == "*"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def map_position
    @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] = @value
    @board.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] = @value
  end

  def recursion
    if @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] == 0
      (@row - 1..@row + 1).each do |r|
        (@col - 1..@col + 1).each do |c|
          unless (r - 1 < 0 || r - 1 > @proxi.size - 1) || (c - 1 < 0 || c - 1 > @proxi.size - 1)
            @row, @col = r, c 
            detect
            map_position
            recursion
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def reset
    @row, @col, @value = 0, 0, 0
  end
end

d = Detector.new(b, b)
b.print_board
```

If the output has plenty of free space in the upper right corner proceed to pasting the next part, else repaste.

```
d.row = 1
d.col = 1
d.mine?
d.detect
d.map_position
d.recursion
b.print_board
```

It will error out with a stack level too deep error at the recursion method. I know this is because it is having issues ending the recursive pattern. I thought my two unless statements deterring it from searching off the board would limit it to the area in the board. Plus the mines would force it to be limited in zeros it can expose. Maybe it is somehow writing spaces off the board or overwriting things on the board?

Comment: Disregarding stack errors, your code is very oddly written. Your choice of classes adds unnecessary complexity, most of your methods don't accept arguments even when they should, and you use instance variables inappropriately. You might want to read more tutorials before tackling a program this complex.

Comment: This comment right here is what convinced me I am quitting programming. I hope nobody else waists there time trying to help me here because I am not even going to bother trying to make this work. Files went strait to the trash can along with every reference I have ever collected on C++ python or ruby. Going to go travel then kill myself at the end.

Comment: Hey now, no need to get dramatic. You clearly have a knack for programming. Your use of instance variables maybe be "improper" for Ruby, but it demonstrates your ability to engineer clever solutions from the tools you are familiar with. Honestly the only real problems with your code are some minor logic errors. As you become more familiar with the language you will find ways to structure you code in a way to find and avoid such issues.

Comment: Sorry Max. I suffer from type 1 bi-polar and I refuse taking meds for it after having a life threatening allergic reaction to the crap they tried to push on me. None the less I did rage delete all my local content but it should be backed up on Github.

Comment: I get what you are saying, one of the solutions presented to me over an earlier build of this thing was to encapsulate the loops I am using to check surround the spaces and "yield" the "r" "c" iteration variables. I am not very keen at the "yield" command yet so will be reading up on it after work.

Comment: I think the idea was so that I can isolate those "r" "c" variables to the methods scope and not the objects scope. I think I get what you are saying about the instance variables, I am over-using them yes? Something like this that through a fractal sense, spreads out to solve the different tiles would probably be best isolated to a smaller region of scope then the entire detect object instance?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me, I know it can be frustrating trying to explain things to people when they don’t understand the larger scope of the knowledge-base. Trust me I work for geeksquad, I deal with people like that every day so sometimes I need to step back and see how those meta patterns flow through life because even I fall into the same boat among a different spectrum of professionals. I will take another crack at this tonight. Thank you for your support sir!

Comment: Correct about the scope. Restricting the variables to the method scope is especially important with recursion since the object scope is global to all method calls.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need a recursion here. Simply check each position for mines around:

*Please always use 0-based arrays to eliminate lots of `@blah - 1`.*

In `detect` you need to return immediately if there is a mine and set the `@value` otherwise:

```
def detect
  return if @proxi.board[@row][@col] == '*'
  value = 0 # no need to be global anymore
  (@row - 1..@row + 1).each do |r| 
    (@col - 1..@col + 1).each do |c| 
      unless r < 0 || r >= @proxi.size || c < 0 || c >= @proxi.size
        value += 1 if @proxi.board[r][c] == "*" 
      end
    end 
  end
  @proxi.board[@row][@col] = value
end
```

Now you don’t need `map_position` method at all. Simply check all the cells:

```
def check
  (0..@proxi.size - 1).each do |r|
    (0..@proxi.size - 1).each do |c|
      @row, @col = r, c
      detect
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Recursion is useful in minesweeper since continuous regions of 0s are usually revealed with a single click. Recursion can "flood" the region without visiting every cell of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Exceeding the stack size is usually an indication that your recursion does not have the correct terminating condition. In your case, what mechanism is in place to prevent `recursion` from being called multiple times with the same `@row` `@col` pair? Note that of the 9 pairs that `(@row - 1..@row + 1)` `(@col - 1..@col + 1)` produce, one of those pairs is `@row` `@col` itself. The function will call itself infinitely many times!

A simple way to solve this would be to have something like a `revealed` array that keeps track of visited cells. Then `recursion` would mark each cell it visits as visited and return immediately if it is called on an already visited cell.

Additionally, your use of instance variables is extremely fragile here. Recursion relies on the fact that each function call has its own scope, but every call of `recursion` shares the same instance variables - which you're using to pass arguments! You should be using method arguments to keep the scopes distinct.